# Consolidating fact records by timestamp

Tags: sql-server, fact, dirty-data

I am in a Microsoft SQL Server database.  I would like to consolidate start and end periods for employees.  For example, given the following simple table:

```
create table dbo.foo (
employee_key bigint,
effective_start_date date,
effective_end_date date,
account_name varchar(100));


insert into foo (employee_key,
effective_start_date,
effective_end_date,
account_name)
values (1
    ,'2017-01-01'
    ,'2017-01-31'
    ,'Google')
,(1
    ,'2017-02-01'
    ,'2017-02-28'
    ,'Apple')
,(1
    ,'2017-03-01'
    ,'2017-03-31'
    ,'Google')
,(1
    ,'2017-04-01'
    ,'9999-12-31'
    ,'Google')
```

The employee has moved accounts a couple times.  I would like to maintain the change in February and back again.  However, I do not want to see 2 records at the end.  Instead, I want the tenure at Google to run from 2017-03-01 to 9999-12-31.

By the way, this is one example.  That is, the "broken" records aren't always at the end of the employee's tenure.

Expected results:

```
employee_key | effective_start_date | effective_end_date | account_name
1            | 2017-01-01           | 2017-01-31         | Google
1            | 2017-02-01           | 2017-02-28         | Apple
1            | 2017-03-01           | 9999-12-31         | Google
```

Comment: Can you post your expected results?  Don't explain them - actually show us the columns and rows that you want returned.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  A bigger concern is how this data is being inserted into your table.  Why is a new record created, instead of updating the `effective_end_date` of the appropriate record?

Comment: I think the simplest answer is:  dirty data.  Or that another minor attribute of the fact (that I am ignoring) changed.  But if I don't care about this minor attribute, I want to be able to regroup my data.  I thought this might be an insurmountable problem, and if so, that's fine.  I just need to tell my boss.

Comment: It is not insurmountable.  You could easily solve this with a `CURSOR` however, I am trying to come up with a better solution using CTEs.  Is it possible in your data to have THREE consecutive employee key/account name combinations?  In your sample data, it only occurs with TWO consecutive records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use row_number and get this results... I used two subqueries but it can be solved without that as well:

```
;With Cte as (
select *, Bucket = sum(accn) over(partition by employee_key order by effective_start_date) 
    from (
        Select *,case when account_name <> lag(account_name) over(partition by employee_key order by effective_start_date) 
            then 1 else 0 end as AccN
            from foo ) A
    )
    Select top (1) with ties employee_key, Min(effective_start_date) over(partition by employee_key,Bucket) AS [effective_start_date],      
                Max(effective_end_date) over(partition by employee_key,Bucket) AS [effective_end_date], account_name
    from cte
    order by row_number() over(partition by employee_key, bucket order by effective_start_date)
```

Output as below:

```
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| employee_key | Effective_start_Date | Effective_End_date | account_name |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|            1 | 2017-01-01           | 2017-01-31         | Google       |
|            1 | 2017-02-01           | 2017-02-28         | Apple        |
|            1 | 2017-03-01           | 9999-12-31         | Google       |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XMEM33958)

Comment: Yep so only I used partition by employee_key while calculating AccN and also in the outer sum

Comment: Could you please explain the bucket, sum(accn) logically?  I am trying to understand this query.

Comment: Try executing sub-query separately, you will understand the bucket creation

Comment: I did that first - but it is still confusing to me.

Comment: Inner subquery will give 1 or 0 if the current account_name is equivalent to next account_name based on lag() and do sum with windowing function so that it will create our bucket... We eventually need to separate first google, apple and then you will get different id for next google

Comment: I'll have to look more into it, myself, but thank you for explaining.  However, `LAG()` gets the PREVIOUS row, not the NEXT row (that's `LEAD()`)

Comment: Also will this handle multiple employees?

Comment: Yep so only I used partition by employee_key

Comment: Why is the outer row_number not partitioning by Employee_Key as well?

Comment: yep outer needs to be also partitioned... updated with demo

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this SQL

```
-- Table to group by
SELECT Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           ORDER BY employee_key, effective_start_date, effective_end_date) RN, 
       *, 
       Cast(NULL AS BIGINT) 
       GroupBy 
INTO   #tmp 
FROM   #foo 

-- Variables 
DECLARE @GroupBy BIGINT = 0 
DECLARE @lastEmployee_key BIGINT 
DECLARE @lastAccount_Name VARCHAR(100) 


--- Creating the data group 
UPDATE #tmp 
SET    @GroupBy = groupby = CASE 
                              WHEN employee_key = Isnull(@lastEmployee_key, -1) 
                                   AND account_name = Isnull(@lastAccount_Name, 
                                                      '') 
                                   THEN @GroupBy 
                              ELSE @GroupBy + 1 
                            END, 
       @lastEmployee_key = employee_key = employee_key, 
       @lastAccount_Name = account_name = account_name 


--- Output 
SELECT employee_key, 
       Min(effective_start_date) effective_start_date, 
       Max(effective_end_date)   effective_end_date, 
       account_name 
FROM   #tmp 
GROUP  BY groupby, 
          employee_key, 
          account_name
```

The result is

```
employee_key | effective_start_date|effective_end_date | account_name
-------------| --------------------|------------------ | -------------
1            | 2017-01-01          |2017-01-31         | Google
1            | 2017-02-01          |2017-02-28         | Apple
1            | 2017-03-01          |9999-12-31         | Google
```

Comment: This is an incomplete solution.  For instance: Your example implies employee 1 worked on the Google account on 2/2/2017.  But row two of the original data clearly shows she worked on Apple.

Comment: Write here the expect result do you want. if you want some think like it:

employee_key | account_name | effective_start_date|effective_end_date 
1            | Apple        | 2017-02-01          |2017-02-28
1            | Google       | 2017-01-01          |9999-12-31

the query is select employee_key , account_name , min(effective_start_date) effective_start_date , max(effective_end_date)  effective_end_date from #foo group by account_name, employee_key

Comment: This is incorrect because the span includes time when the employee's account name was Apple (February, 2017).

Comment: Please, write here the expected result

Comment: employee_key         Start Date End Date   account_name
-------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    2017-01-01 2017-01-31 Google
1                    2017-02-01 2017-02-28 Apple
1                    2017-03-01 9999-12-31 Google